# Group Policy Preference Event id in Window XP

Tags: group-policy, windows-event-log, windows-xp

Whenever Group Policy Preference get auto-update after 90 minutes interval on Window XP. Is there any event id generated or not in Window XP?

Please answer in Yes or No.

If yes than what is Event Id number in Window XP ?

PS- i found the related Question about this GPP, but not the exact answer, so thought to ask all of you once again. Sorry for any inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

By default no, but you can configure logging in a GPO for each Preference type: `Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy\Logging and tracing`.
A successfull GPP object application has the id 4096.

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002507) contains the list of events generated this way.